# Can not join tables with LINQ

Tags: linq

I will glad if you help me

I have 4 tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMIdn.png

I need to get a ApptNumber from Condo and ContractID from Contract
If no contracts assigned to the condo, leave it blank.

Like this:

| Cnds | Cntrcts |
|--------|-----------|
|  101     | contr1     |
|  102     | contr2     |
|  103     | contr3     |
|  104     |                 |
|  105     |                 |
|  106     | contr4     |
|  107     |                       |
|--------|-----------|

I tried to do it like this, but failed to get the right result

```
var q =
from c in condos
join b in buildings on c.buildingID equals b.BuildingId
join t in tenants on b.BuildingId equals t.buildingID
join ct in contracts on t.TenantID equals ct.tenantID into result
from subresult in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{ 
    c.apptNumber, 
    contract = (subresult == null ? 0 : subresult.ContractID)                    
};
```

Sincerely

Comment: Your linq-to-<??> model should have navigation properties. Use them.

Comment: Are the SuiteNo and apptNumber same? How do you know a contract is for which condo?

Comment: @Gert Arnold Link-to-SQL. Sorry, what do you mean ?

Comment: @AD.Net Yes, they are the same. That is the reason why I need to join those tables.

Comment: It might help of you shared a working Sql query that does the join, to avoid questions about your domain model.

Comment: @neontapir Ok, I will try to code an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
from c in context.Condos
join ct in context.Contracts on c.apptNumber equals ct.SuiteNo into j 
  //it could be another field for joining
from d in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {c.apptNumber, Contract = d != null ? d.ContractId : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. It was my fault to use multiple JOINS in first place.

I resolved the issue like that:

```
var q =
from c in condos
join ct in contracts on c.apptNumber equals ct.SuiteNo into j //it could be another field
from d in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { c.apptNumber, Contract = d != null ? d.ContractID : 0 };
var q2 = q.GroupBy(c => c.apptNumber).Select(group => group.First());
```